# Android, how to add some right padding to text in a spinner?

Tags: android, coding-style, padding

I'm developing an Android app (API level 8).

How do I add some right padding to the style of spinners layout?

With the default (Theme.black) style, the right arrow box is placed too close to the end of text in the (closed) spinner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your xml, use the `android:paddingRight` attribute.

Comment: How to do it programmatically? is it spinner.setPAdding(10,10,10,10);

Comment: @hardcoded, use `spinner.setPadding(0,0,10,0);`. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file for the layout, use, for example

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
```

Comment: This adds a margin *outside* the spinner, I need padding *inside* it (between text and the box with the down arrow). android:paddingRight is ok. Thanks.